# Why doesn't jQuery make all functions "live" automatically?

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't jQuery allow click(), bind() and similar functions to work "live" automatically?

Why do I need to use `live("click", functi...` if I want to make it work `"live"`,  instead of `click(function()...`? Does live takes more resources?

Comment: Oh geez, I suppose because sanity says the browser needs to know when it's need to respond, not "willy-nilly-event-o-rama". The [`$.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method operates on changes to the `document`, so the more specific you are (and not each and every "event"), the more "efficient" the event handling you have in the end.

Comment: `.live()` is event delegation. That would make every event on the page be tested against every selector provided for that event. That would be bad, and that's why `.live()` is bad *(and deprecated)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Funny you should ask that. Someone wrote an entire article answering your question:
http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/why-jquery-live-is-a-bad-option-to-use/

> On the surface live and delegate can seem interchangeable. However,
>   they are not. Live has several serious disadvantages and should never
>   be used, and this article will explain why.

The outlined summary is:

1. You can’t use live for reusable widgets
2. stopPropagate() doesn’t work in live
3. Live is slower
4. Live isn’t chainable

Comment: Answers should contain the gist of the article that was linked (probably can just rip the numbered outline out of that page).  Definitely worth an upvote once you add that :)

Comment: Thanks @MerlynMorgan-Graham. I learn how to improve my answers every day!